# Is the shorten question mark colon ?: a Objective-C syntax?

Tags: objective-c

Xcode does not give an error of my *(thought-to-be)* typo:

```
 NSString *theme = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"theme"];
 NSLog(@"Theme: %@", theme ?: @"Default");
```

It turns out:

```
 NSLog(@"Theme: %@", theme ?: @"Default");
```

works same as:

```
 NSLog(@"Theme: %@", theme ? theme : @"Default");
```

Is the above shorten syntax good for [gcc only](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3f%3a#C)? Or it is part of Objective-C?

Comment: The link you gave specifically stated that it was a GNU extension to the _C_ language. It makes no mention of Objective-C, which is a superset of C.

Comment: This is the best thing I've read on SO all month. I love learning new shit!!

Comment: How is `a ?: b` different to `a || b` ?

Comment: @jamesfisher I believe `||` is just a boolean OR operator, so while `a ?: b` would evaluate to either the `a` or `b` object, `a || b` would evaluate to a boolean.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's a GNU extension to the conditional expression in C:

From [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3A#C):

> A GNU extension to C allows omitting the second operand, and using
>   implicitly the first operand as the second also:

```
a = x ? : y;
```

Comment: I also quoted the wikipedia link in my question. As Apple is moving away from gcc to llvm, I am curious to know whether it's official syntax in Objective-C.

Comment: @ohho Yeah I didn't see the link in your question.  They are moving towards clang, which provides compatibility with GCC 4.2, so keeps the GNU extensions.